# adding { - } in a for loop : c programming

Tags: c

the program runs fine and clear, but i just wanted to ask why didnt we add { - } in the beggining and end of the for loop ? the program runs fine without adding them but when i tried to add { - } in the for loop the prgram didnt run fine, arent we suppose to add { - } in ever begging and end of every loop ? and why did the program run fine without them and didnt run fine with them ?

```
int c, first, last, middle, n, search, array[100];

   printf("Enter number of elements\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      scanf("%d",&array[c]);

   printf("Enter value to find\n");
   scanf("%d",&search);

   first = 0;
   last = n - 1;
   middle = (first+last)/2;

   while( first <= last )
   {
      if ( array[middle] < search )
         first = middle + 1;    
      else if ( array[middle] == search ) 
      {
         printf("%d found at location %d.\n", search, middle+1);
         break;
      }
      else
         last = middle - 1;

      middle = (first + last)/2;
   }
   if ( first > last )
      printf("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", search);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'didn't run fine'?

Comment: Please provide the entire text of a program that doesn't "run fine". see http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: `printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);` ---->>> `printf("Enter %d ORDERED integers\n", n);`

Comment: I don't understand why didn't it run *fine* with the braces. What error did you get.

Comment: @darksphere why haven't you accepted any of your question's answer. You have already asked 3 ques but you haven't accepted any

Comment: im new here sorry, i realy dnt know how do i accept the answers, can u show me ?

Comment: @darksphere: Welcome to SO! Your status suggests you have not yet read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page. Please do so soon. Help on common questions can be found, remarkably, in the section called [The Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @darksphere you can easily accept and answer by clicking on the `tick mark right sign` see here http://i40.tinypic.com/2z4bt41.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Without braces it takes **ONE statement** as its scope

like

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
 scanf("%d",&array[c]);
```

Equivalent of

```
 for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
{
  scanf("%d",&array[c]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop executes the statement immediately after it in a loop. What is a statement? It can be:

A piece of code ended with `;`.

A block of code started with `{` and ended with `}`.

Your for-loop

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
  scanf("%d",&array[c]);
```

uses the first definition of statement, but you could also write it as

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
{
  scanf("%d",&array[c]);
}
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Informally: The for-loop has a one-statement body. To use multiple statements, you nest them in a block-statement.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one statement in the block the braces are optional